# not able to iterate on FormArray

Tags: angular, angular-material

am using approach of
-- formGroup --
-- FormControl -- , -- FormArray --
-----------------   -- FormControlList --

I have also tried FormArray within nested Form Group

But am not able to iterate Form Array, Please let me know if approach is right.

HTML Error--: Object possibly 'null' - controls

CODE -

```
HTML --
<form [formGroup]="abcForm">
    <section>
<div formArrayName="title">
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let control of abcForm.get('title').controls; let i= index;">
       {{i}}
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
</form>
```

/////////////////////

```
TS --

titles: any = [
    {
      name: "one",
      value: "one",
      selected: false
    },
    {
      name: "two",
      value: "two",
      selected: true
    },
    {
      name: "three",
      value: "three",
      selected: true
    },
  ];

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder)
this.abcForm = this.fb.group({
      one: ['',Validators.required],
      title:
        this.buildTitleControls()
      ,
    });

buildTitleControls() {
    const arr = this.titles.map((val : any) => {
      return this.fb.control('');
    });
    return this.fb.array(arr);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to add `?` to `abcForm.get('title')`.

```
<li *ngFor="let control of abcForm.get('title')?.controls; let i= index;">
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put an *ngIf on your form:

```html
<form [formGroup]="abcForm" *ngIf="abcForm">
```

It's rendering before your formGroup is done initializing.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a getter for `title` to retrieve controls as `FormArray`.

And for HTML use `title.controls`.

```js
get title(): FormArray {
  return this.abcForm.controls['title'] as FormArray;
}
```

```
<li *ngFor="let control of title.controls; let i = index">
  {{ i }}
</li>
```

[Sample Solution on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qfyhlc?file=src/app/app.component.html)